# Did leaflet-bing-layer change? (Angular 6)

Tags: leaflet, basemap

So for the development of my app I've been using Esri's basemap.  I wanted to switch to bing.  This is my import as i saw in another question asked here.

```
import 'leaflet-bing-layer';
```

Then this is in my ngOnInit? The map loads fine but none of the other types besides the default Aerial will show up?  Any ideas

```
L.tileLayer.bing('key', {
      type: 'Road'
    }
).addTo(this.map);
```

Comment: I was able to switch it to 'Road' by editing the index.js file in the node modules.  Will update if I found a way to edit in my component.ts